# Eliminating false positives detected by an OpenCV face classifier

Tags: python, opencv, cascade-classifier

I am working with thermal videos. My project determines in real-time whether each frame contains a face or not. By "contains a face", I mean this:

[image]

(*one face, this size and angle, per frame*)

I've trained an LBP cascade classifier for this purpose. The classifier performs pretty well and is able to detect thermal faces with very low chance of false negative as shown above. However, the rate of false positives is quite alarming. Non-face objects in the void are detected, as shown below.

[image] [image] 
[image]

*Note: these images were used as negative samples*

By adjusting parameters of `detectMultiScale` method, the number of false positives can be reduced. But still, with a `scaleFactor` of 1.5 and `minNeighbors` of 10, I get false positives 20% of the time.

For the cascade training I had 600 negative images (60x80) and 90 positive images (60x50), out of which 1200 positive samples were generated.

So what are other possible solutions or work-around for this problem, without compromising speed of detection or frame rate?

**EDIT:** I have tried extracting hard negatives from my samples by using the trained classifier on the negative images and marking up the false negatives to include them in the next training. So far, I have been able to reduce the false positives to about 12%.  However i am still not satisfied with this result.

Comment: 1. During training use much more/different negatives. 2. during detection maybe you can use some clever post-processing.

Comment: Hi Micka. I read about computing the histogram of the detected object and comparing it to that of an average face, but that seems tedious for the program. Can you suggest something in particular?

Comment: sorry, never worked with thermal imaging. Maybe assume that faces will have some minimum average intensity? This should eliminate the first two of your three sample false positives. Did you try to train an additional haar cascade classifier? You could combine both and only accept if both detect some region as a face.

Comment: How big was your training data?

Comment: i have 600 negative images (60x80) and 90 positive images (60x50) out of which 1200 positive samples were generated.

Comment: take a look at the paper in [this post](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/7910) i think it will be helpful for better training

Comment: Thanks sturkmen. That looks promising!